# how to create a raster from ascii file

Tags: r, gis, r-raster

I want to create a raster from ASCII file using package `raster` function `raster`

According to documentation this should work:

`ras <- raster("fname.asc")`

However it fails:

`Error in .local(x, ...) : could not find function ".fullFilename"`

Although this works fine:

`ras <- stack("fname.asc")[[1]]`

Can anyone see a reason for this?

EDIT:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)
other attached packages:
[1] rgdal_1.0-4   raster_2.4-15 sp_1.1-1    `
```

Comment: Please include the version numbers for R and `raster` that you are using from `sessionInfo()`

Comment: My guess is that this is because of using a saved R session or something odd like that. Either way, first update the raster package to its current version, and check again.

Comment: @RobertH, I've updated raster_2.4-20, as well as sp and rgdal, but still getting same results. I wonder can anyone even reproduce this, or is it unique to my system?

Comment: Did you make sure not to load a previous R session? The error is unique for you, I think; otherwise many would have complained as `raster('filename')` is one the most used functions.

Comment: That's fixed it, thank you.

Comment: The semi-automatic saving and loading of sessions is one the worst features of R --- causes a lot of trouble, for very little benefit. It is OK that is possible, but it should not be suggested.